# Проблема с gui python

Tags: python, gui

у меня вопрос. Я разрабатываю проект на python pygame и есть одна проблема. Если я хочу отрисовать полигон, часть которого находиться вне экрана, то pygame все равно её отрисовывает. И порой эта часть может быть очень большой и из за этого очень сильно проседает fps. Как заставить pygame неотрисовывать невидимую часть полигона? (я отрисовываю полигон, если хотя бы одна точка находится внутри экрана) Если такого способа нет, то посоветуйте фреймворк типа pygame для python, в котором не тратятся ресурсы не отрисовку полигонов вне экрана. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Можете код добавить?

Comment: К сожалению нет, так как код слишком громадный, но могу рассказать в общих чертах. Я написал некий алгоритм, который возвращает 3 точки в формате x y. И любая из этих точек может находиться за пределами экрана и на достаточно большом расстоянии друг от друга. Как я говорил, если хотя-бы одна точка находится на экране, то полигон отрисовывается. И из за этого полигон может быть настолько большим, что pygame, жертвуя fps, тратит много ресурсов для его отрисовки, даже той части, которая не находится на экране.